# "but" followed by adverb

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

Is the usage "but implicitly" in the following sentence correct?

> B is also assumed but implicitly.

The context is as follows. We know that both "A" and "B" are assumed. But compared with "A", the assumption "B" is only implicit.

Comment: If it helps, 1. the "But" is is an adverb and is the equivalent of "However" 2. "But compared with "A"," is a shortened form of "But, **when it is** compared with "A","

Comment: Arguably, a comma or dash is preferable: _B is also assumed, but implicitly._ Perhaps a better way of showing the extended sentence is _B is also assumed, but in this case implicitly._ But as Greybeard says, A must have been assumed and this assumption spelled out.

Answer (score -1):

It is correct, but I doubt it is formal. You know, the online dictionaries love to explain adverbs in a format like this "in a [adjective] way". So, why not try to replace it in your sentence and it can be read as "B is also assumed but in an implicit way", which sounds totally fine.

Comment: Why is "in an implicit way" better than "implicitly"?

Comment: @RosieF Sorry, I should have made myself clearer. I'm not saying it is a better way to express, but they are interchangeable and the other way sounds totally fine, which makes the sentence in the question sounds totally fine as well.